# Включение и отключение кнопки JavaScript

Tags: javascript

хотел бы задать вопрос, у нас есть счётчик а, и две кнопки, плюс и минус и при каждом клике на плюс, счётчик а увеличивается, на 20-ый клик, кнопка плюс, должна отключиться, если же нажать на минус, счётчик должен стать на единицу меньше, и кнопка плюс должна разблокироваться и мне бы хотелось узнать, как это возможно воплотить в коде.
я пытался сделать так, но disabled не хочет убираться

```
if(a==20){this.disabled = true;}
if(a==19){this.disabled = false;}
```

Comment: Так вы весь алгоритм написали. Сделайте всё точно так, как написано.

Comment: Если будут траблы с кодом, что он не работает как надо, не то делает, то приходите, пишите его - коллеги посмотрят, помогут.

Comment: пытался, но он не хочет убирать disabled

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ВЕСЬ код, который некорректно не работает. Опишите конкретно что там не работает

Comment: Предоставьте html, css (если есть) и js. Потому что пока не ясно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как это возможно воплотить в коде

Например так :

```js
const result = document.querySelector('#result')
const add = document.querySelector('#add')
const subtract = document.querySelector('#subtract')

add.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let c = +result.textContent

  result.textContent = ++c

  if (c == 20) e.target.disabled = true
  subtract.disabled = false
})

subtract.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let c = +result.textContent

  result.textContent = --c

  if (c == 0) e.target.disabled = true
  add.disabled = false
})
```

```html
<button id="subtract" disabled="true">-</button>
<label id="result">0</label>
<button id="add">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете атрибут `disabled` попробуйте таким образом отключить кнопку.

```
<button disabled="true">Increment</button>
```

При помощи JS соответственно управлять изменением атрибута. Без имеющегося кода сложно сказать что вам нужно.

Comment: там кода на 3к строк, и проект полностью уникален в своём роде, и если я его сюда скину, то поверь, его скомуниздят

Comment: @Leonerdo ой, да лааааадно. вы не можете код написать со счётчиком самостоятельно, а, значит, этот проект совсем лайтовый. Потому что уникальные проекты пишут профи.

Comment: @Leonerdo И вас никто не заставляет весь код выкладывать. а только тот локализированный участок где есть проблема.

Comment: лайтовый говоришь, окей)))
посмотрим.